# Mapping fields conditionally with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I have a `Food` object which has a one-to-many relationship with other `Food` objects (through the field `ingredients`) and most of the time I want to load the `ingredients` with the parent `Food` object. However, when I load a `Food` object, its `ingredients` load, then their `ingredients` load, then their `ingredients` load, ad nauseam. Is there any way to prevent Hibernate from recursively loading `ingredients` and instead just load the `Food` objects' base information (like `id` and `type`)?

Food

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Foods")
public class Food { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="Description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="food")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
    .
    .
    .
```

Ingredient

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Ingredients")
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {       
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FoodId")
    private Food food;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="IngredientId")
    private Food ingredient;

    @Column(name="Amount")
    private int amount;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: paste food entity source code

Comment: @PeterŠály Added it as well as the join table object `Ingredient`

Comment: OneToMany has default fetch type LAZY. That seems to be ok. Aren't you iterating getIngredients() from somewhere?

Comment: @PeterŠály When Hibernate is mapping the `Food` object and gets the ingredients, it then gets the ingredients of the ingredient etc... Is the fetch type what controls the "depth" of mapping?

Answer (score 0):

The loading of collections can be done

1. by eagerly fetching @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER). If no fetch attribute specified default fetch type is LAZY. In your case fetch type is not causing it.
2. by accessing ingredients collection inside session, hibernate will initialize/load it using select from DB. This can happen when iterating collection or calling `food.getIngredients().size()` or `food.getIngredients().isEmpty()` or other methods.

I assume some code is accessing collection and this is causing it.